# Python List Comprehension: assign to multiple variables

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to assign to multiple variables in a one-liner?

Let's say I have a list of 3D points and I want x, y and z lists.

```py
polygon = [(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0)]

# this works to get the expected result, but is not a single list comprehension
x = [x for x, y, z in polygon ]
y = [y for x, y, z in polygon ]
z = [z for x, y, z in polygon ]
```

I am thinking of something like:

```py
x, y, z = [... for x, y, z in polygon ]
```

Comment: look for `zip(*polygon)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip()` function:

```
polygon = [(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0)]

x, y, z = zip(*polygon)

print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
```

Prints:

```
(0, 1, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

---

Or if you want lists instead of tuples:

```
x, y, z = map(list, zip(*polygon))
```

Answer (score 2):

Unpack the list of tuples using `zip()`:

```
polygon = [(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0)]

x,y,z = zip(*polygon)

print(list(x))
print(list(y))
print(list(z))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**EDIT**:

If you want the lists:

```
x,y,z = [list(a) for a in zip(*polygon)]
```